# Cannot load WiX projects after installing the VS2010 Web Publishing Updates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, wix, publishing

I installed the VS2010 web publishing updates yesterday, and now whenever I try to load a WiX setup project (all showing as unloaded in solution explorer) I'm getting the error:

The imported project "PROJECTNAME.wpp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.5\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets

Where PROJECTNAME is the path to my setup wixproj file, without the .wixproj extension. I've checked through the project file and there is no reference to a wpp.targets file anywhere. I decided to try and create a blank targets file in that location and so added one with just this in it:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
</Project>
```

But got exactly the same error - a not found exception despite the file being there!

I then dug into the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file and had a look for any ".wpp.targets" text, which gave me this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(EnableWebPublishProfileFile)'=='true' And 
    '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' != '' And Exists($(WebPublishProfileFile)) ">
  <WebPublishProfileCustomizeTargetFile Condition="'$(WebPublishProfileCustomizeTargetFile)'==''">
    $([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($(WebPublishProfileFile), '.wpp.targets'))
  </WebPublishProfileCustomizeTargetFile>
  ...
```

So that looks to be setting up a filename of PROJECTNAME.wpp.targets, but only when the EnableWebPublishProfileFile property is set to true. I added this to my wixproj file's main propertygroup:

```
<EnableWebPublishProfileFile>False</EnableWebPublishProfileFile>
```

Again though, it made no difference at all to the error. I'm running out of ideas here now!

**Further update**

I've been trying to repo this on a blank project (so far without success), and the messing about has narrowed the error down to this line (186) in the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file:

```
<Import Project="$(WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile)" 
Condition="'$(WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile)' != ''"/>
```

This is set at the top of the file:

```
<WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile
    Condition="'$(WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile)'==''">
  $(WebPublishPipelineProjectDirectory)\*.wpp.targets
</WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile>
```

I'm not sure how this is getting changed to PROJECTNAME.wpp.targets though?

I tried overriding this in my project file, but once again, it makes no difference at all.

Next I added an Exists() condition to the line in the targets file, now some projects are working and others are not, instead failing (on build) with the error:

*The "DisableEscapeMSBuildVariable" parameter is not supported by the "ImportParametersFile" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.*

My journey continues...

Comment: I'm unable to repro this, can someone provide some steps to repro?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue when trying to open a standard web project.

The proj file was referencing the following import for v10.0 targets but throwing the import error in the question which referred to v10.5 targets.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />
```

The same was true when I referenced a hard coded path - I still got v10.5 error

My solution was to simply back up and remove that version located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.5
```

I'm really not sure what other programs and projects need this version or why import paths were not followed but it go this project open for me seeming falling back to the correct version.